# Passing props to higher-order components

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, jsx, higher-order-components

Lets say if we have the following HOC:

```
const myHoc = someProps => ComposedComponent => {
  const propsToPass = { /* ...some calculations... */ }; 
  return <ComposedComponent {...propsToPass} />;
};
```

How would I pass a prop to `ComposedComponent` in `myHoc` outside of `myHoc`?

## Use case

I am writing an app used with [`redux-orm`](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm/). Naturally, I'd want to implement the classical idea of abstracting the view layer (dumb components) from the data layer with HOCs. Since the models are somewhat uniform, I am using a factory pattern to create these HOCs.

**Factory function signature:**

```
bindDocument(Model)(documentId)(ComposedComponent) => DumbComponentWithDocumentProps
```

In my app, I have a rich editor that can "select" these documents. The `documentId` of these selected documents are then stored in the redux store. I have trouble wrapping my head around writing a HOC for binding the selected document to a dumb component using the above factory function.

**Example desired function signature:**

```
bindSelectedMovieTicketDocument(ComposedComponent) => DumbComponentWithDocumentProps
```

I could manually retrieve the store and get the selected document ids but that just smells bad to me.

The alternative solution would be to use HOC to bind the selected document id to a wrapping component that would then use the id (from it's props) to create another HOC with the document-binding HOC. This works but would require a lot of boilerplate code just to pass the id around.

Comment: can you explain a bit.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be restructuring your code to allow this?

Comment: @hannadrehman I've added my use case

Comment: An option to consider: [render props](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce)

Answer (score 0):

```
var bindHOC = (model) => (DumbComp) => {
   return connect(state=>state.docID, null)(() => <DumbComp model={model}>);
}
```

This will pass `docID` as prop from redux store to `DumbComp` along with `model` as prop from input param.

This way we can avoid 2 HOCs.